# Same Modal Bootstrap but different info from DB deppending on ID?

Tags: php, jquery, database, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I'm new on this world, and I am trying to learn some in PHP with LARAVEL and JavaScript.

I'm trying to make a page with some post with some information and a button "read more".

I already have the correct information in the list coming from DB. 
At the button I can catch the "ID" from each post.

So, the problem is.. when I click on modal button, I have always the same info from DB, from the first post.

tt's possible to create an onClick function javascript to show me the info, like "show me the info from this ID"??? 
And how I can do this? Because I no have idea how!

This is my button code:

```
<button class="btn" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" value="{{$news->id}}" OnClick="Show(this);"> Read More </button>
```

And if I make a consolelog I can catch de ID in a javascript..

```
function Show(btn){
console.log(btn.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create some modal and append post id to modal id and call that

```
<button class="btn" role="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newModal-{{$news->id}}"> Read More </button>
```

and for your modal :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="newModal-{{$new->id}}" ...
```

Comment: It's works!! Thanks a lot!! I've spent days thinking about this! and I hope one day think quickly like you haha!! Thanks!

Comment: thanks , if my answer was correct for you , pls accept my answer :)